# Default page returns 404 only when using search bot user agent

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I have created a website using ASP.NET web pages (not MVC, not web forms).

If I access the default page by mydomain.com in a browser it shows the default page (index.cshtml) fine. However, search engines are seeing a 404 page and if I change my user agent to Googlebot or Bingbot I get a 404 error too.

This only affects the default page - if I use mydomain.com/index.cshtml I don't get the 404 page.

There is no user agent detection in my code.

I have watched the headers and there is no redirections, just an immediate 404 response only when using a bot user agent.

Is there some built-in user agent detection that affects default pages in ASP.NET web pages? Or could my hosting company be doing something (Arvixe)?

I can add code if it helps (but not sure what code I would add), or link to the web site.

Comment: seems like your webserver is blocking the access

Comment: It only happens for the default page (/) - all other pages (/xyz, /abc.cshtml) all work fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem.

Apparently Arvixe websites have been hacked. The hackers inserted some code in web.config that displayed a different URL in place of the home page for bots only...

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="1" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^$" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Googlebot|Yahoo|MSNBot|bingbot" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="bot.asp" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I did see title/description for sports jerseys in Bing search for my website which is why I was investigating this.

From a search it appears this has affected lots of Arvixe customers, most will probably never know as they are unlikely to see their website with a search bot user agent.

It looks like Arvixe were aware of the hacking and have already put a stop to this by removing the spam file (bot.asp or bot.php) but they have not fixed the web.config. If you have shared hosting with Arvixe you should check for this now.

You should also check your Google search console/analytics accounts for owners/users added as some have reported this too, although you would have got an email warning of this.

I changed all my Arvixe passwords but I doubt they got individual account passwords, they probably hacked at the server level.